# Performance of ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

We've been doing some performance testing of our application
Due to legacy issues, our entire application is not React. Our application container creates divs which we then pass to ReactDOM.render( .... , div), etc. to render the React control.

Later, when we cleanup, we call ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div) on each of these divs.

What we're noticing when we test with a large number of our react controls, the time taken inside unmountComponentAtNode seems to take longer and is affected by the actual number of controls it has to cleanup even though each control is independent of each other.

As i debug through the unmount function I see things like findCurrentHostFiberWithNoPortals being called so I am wondering if maybe it's trying to find something and

If anyone could shed some light on theories as to why unmounting time seems to increase linearly to the number of controls being unmounted, that would be great. Of course the followup question is what could we possibly do to help React speed up the cleanup/unmounting?

This is an image of the times i logged per control as the number of controls increases (16, 32, etc)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ircgA.png)